# Single cell row with vertically centered image and text?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I tried searching for solutions in stack, but none of the answers I found addressed my issue.

I'm developing an email and I want to have a single cell row that has text with an image in between the text. The cell height is the full height of the image, but I want the text to be vertically centered. The text is now flush on the bottom

Here's my code (there's many inline styles, I apologize in advance). Please note this a single column row that is part of the [fluid hybrid approach](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919) by Nicole Merlin.

```
<tr>
      <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#e2f4ff" style="padding:0">
        <table width="100%" align="center" border="1" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;"> 
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important;;padding:0;text-align:left;padding-bottom: 5px !important;color: #17a0ce;font-weight: bold; Margin:0;font-size:26px; text-align: center;">
              THE<img src="http://www.waldenway.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/largedog.png" alt="ABC's" /> OF SAFE SLEEP FOR DOGS
            </td>
          </tr>              
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just vertically align the image.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#e2f4ff" style="padding:0">
      <table width="100%" align="center" border="1" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important;padding:0;text-align:left;padding-bottom: 5px !important;color: #17a0ce;font-weight: bold; Margin:0;font-size:26px; text-align: center;">
            THE
            <img style="vertical-align: middle !important;" src="http://www.waldenway.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/largedog.png" alt="ABC's" />OF SAFE SLEEP FOR DOGS
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Perfect fix, thank you! I guess I've been looking at this email for too long lol.

Comment: Update, unfortunately Outlook 2007+ isn't working. The text still shows on the bottom of the cell

Comment: Seems like it should (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) but I'd wrap the text parts in `span` tags just as double safety check,

Comment: I tried span tags (even repeating stylings for those span tags and no luck

Comment: Then I guess you'll just have to do the whole thing as an image...Sorry.

Comment: The sad part is that it looks great in Outlook 2003, but not Oultook 2007+

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that works for all email clients is to push them to consider putting that particular image inline with the other text. That can be done by put the text and the image in many `<td>` of the same single row `<tr>`.

This will make you able to define the exact height, width and any other attributes you want of each tag.

Check the following:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#e2f4ff" style="padding:0">
      <table width="100%" align="center" border="1" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important;padding:0;text-align:left;padding-bottom: 5px !important;color: #17a0ce;font-weight: bold; Margin:0;font-size:26px; text-align: center;">
                  THE 
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important;padding:0;">
                  <img style="vertical-align: middle !important;" src="http://www.waldenway.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/largedog.png" alt="ABC's" />
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important;padding:0;text-align:left;padding-bottom: 5px !important;color: #17a0ce;font-weight: bold; Margin:0;font-size:26px; text-align: center;"> OF SAFE SLEEP FOR DOGS
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```